# How should I list my job history in light of mergers, acquisitions, and role changes on my resume?

Tags: resume, work-experience

I'm not looking for a new job right now, in fact I just started a new one a few months ago. But I like to keep my resume up to date at all times, and I am not sure the best way to handle this.

I started with a small business in 2009 right out of college... call that CompanyA. In 2012, CompanyA was purchased by CompanyB. Then we were officially "CompanyA, a wholly owned subsidiary of CompanyB."

In 2014, CompanyB merged with the larger CompanyC, and rebranded as CompanyBC. Around the same time, the company I had started with also rebranded, from CompanyA to CorporationA.

Then, halfway through 2015, I applied for a position in the newly formed CompanyBC and moved across the country for the new position.

The question is this: When I list my job history, how should I note this? How granular should I get? I could just put that I have been at CompanyBC for 6 years, but CompanyBC hasn't even existed that long, since it's a new entity from the merger. I could put that I was at CompanyBC since I moved across the country and before that I was part of CompanyB, but that's not really true either, since I was at CompanyA before we ever started working with CompanyB. I could list each one as a separate entry but then, to someone who doesn't know the story, it looks like I jumped all around and didn't stay places very long.

Is there a universally accepted practice for how to handle a situation like this? I was never taught one during all my resume writing training, so I wasn't sure if there was a standard.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for the link. I am not sure that covers my question though. The OP in the referenced post really never moved jobs or responsibilities - the company just shifted around them. In my case, in addition to all the shifting, I also moved to a new position, in a new office, with added responsibilities (basically moving from an entry level position to a more senior one), away from a company that was a wholly owned subsidiary into the parent company. Does that mean I need to list them as separate entities or can I list it as one big job? I would prefer to establish my seniority and longevity but maybe that's not accurate considering how much my job has changed.
Even if I use the suggested method from that thread it will be confusing. In my case, following the recommendation in the link, the company would be listed as:

CompanyBC (Formerly CorporationA (Formerly CompanyA, A wholly owned subsidiary of CompanyBC (Formerly CompanyB))).

Comment: I thought I'd answered this before: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54947/company-rebranded-and-then-sold-the-area-i-worked-in-how-to-put-that-in-my-resu/54949?s=13|0.0700#54949

Comment: OK, let's simplify. Role1, CorporationA (formerly CompanyA, subsidiary of CompanyBC). Role2, CompanyBC. That keeps the most up-to-date name associated with the role, so they know who you work for now, it includes the name of the company at the time you joined so there won't be any confusion around you being associated with another company name, and it mentions the subsidiary nature of A so that it's clear you're moving up into the parent company. The full history of the mergers and acquisitions doesn't add anything about *you* to your resume.

Comment: see also [What is the accepted method of indicating a company being acquired on a resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/what-is-the-accepted-method-of-indicating-a-company-being-acquired-on-a-resume)